# Programme running on Netbeans but not on CMD

Tags: java, netbeans

I have made an encoding programme in java. It is running well on Netbeans and BlueJ as expected but when I run it on command prompt it is not working properly.

This is my Code :

```
import java.io.*;
class encoder
{
    String ff="",ff2="",key="";
    encoder(String ff,String ff2,String key)
    {
        this.ff=ff;
        this.ff2=ff2;
        this.key=key;
        Encode();
    }
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        new encoder("C:\\Users\\Arpit Jindal\\Desktop\\arpit.txt","C:\\Users\\Arpit Jindal\\Desktop\\encoded.txt","aaa");
    }
    void Encode()
    {
        try
        {
            File f=new File(ff);
            FileReader fis=new FileReader(f);
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fis);
            File f2=new File(ff2);
            f2.createNewFile();
            FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(f2);
            BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(fw);
            int r=0,ln=key.length(),i=0;
            while((r=br.read())!=-1)
            {
                r=r+key.charAt(i)*key.charAt(i)-key.charAt(i);
                r+=5;
                char ch=(char)r;
                i++;
                if(i==(ln-1))
                    i=0;
                bw.write(""+ch);
            }
            bw.close();
            br.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {}
    }
}
```

arpit.txt :

```
fkjbskjbkwgt
```

encoded.txt (after running on Netbeans) :

```
ⓋⓐⓏⓇⓘⓐⓏⓇⓐⓜⓌⓙ
```

encoded.txt (after running on CMD) :

```
????????????
```

Comment: Chances are your console font just doesn't support those characters.

Comment: yaa, that can be the problem. How can i make those character work with cmd

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of charset encoding,you need to set the encoding system for your JVM.
you can set environment variable JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS to -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8" or any other character encoding and it will picked up any JVM starts in your windows machine. JVM will also print "Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8" on console to indicate that it has picked JAVA_TOOS_OPTIONS.

or in your program you can set is as,

```
System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");
```

**Important points to note:**

1) JVM caches value of default character encoding once JVM starts and so is the case for default constructors of InputStreamReader and other core Java classes. So calling System.setProperty("file.encoding" , "UTF-8") may not have desire effect.

2) Always work with your own character encoding if you can, that is more accurate and precise way of converting bytes to Strings.

Comment: System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8") is not working

Comment: what about the env variable setting?

Comment: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8"
encode_gui.java:1: error: illegal character: '\ufeff'
∩╗┐/*
^
encode_gui.java:10: error: class, interface, or enum expected
import java.awt.*;
       ^
2 errors

Comment: :-( Could you please use the below command  javac -encoding UTF8 encoder.java

Comment: it made no difference